# Search through SQL table and delete row if cell already exists

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have a table using SQL Lite with Python. The size of the table always has 3 columns and could have many rows. Each of the cells are strings. Here is example table:

```
serial_num   date_measured  status
1234A        1-1-2015       passed
4321B        6-21-2015      failed
1423C        12-25-2015     passed
```

......

My program prompts me for a serial number. This is saved as a variable called serialNum. How can I delete (or overwrite) an entire row if serialNum equals any of the strings in the serial_num column in my table?

I've seen many examples on how to delete (or overwrite) a row in a table if I know **all** the values in each cell of that row, but my trouble is that the **only** cell that could ever be the same in each row would be the serial number. I need to so a search through the serial_number column and if any string in that column equals the current value of my serialNum variable, I need to delete (or overwrite) that row.

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE test (serial_num text,  date_measured text, status text)''')
c.execute("INSERT INTO test VALUES ('1234A', '1-1-2015', 'passed')")
c.execute("INSERT INTO test VALUES ('4321B', '6-21-2015', 'failed')")
c.execute("INSERT INTO test VALUES ('1423C', '12-25-2015', 'passed')")
conn.commit()
```

Does anyone know a simple way to do this? I've seen others say that an ID must be used or a temporary table, but I would hope there might be an easier way to accomplish my task. Any advice would be great.

Comment: You really shouldn't tag every DBMS you can think of. You should only tag the one you are using.

Answer (score 1):

SQL suports this: simply use delete

```
"delete from test where serial_num=<some input>;"
```

or in this case

```
c.execute("delete from test where serial_num=%s;", serialNum);
```

There's no need to search through the list when using SQL. SQL is declarative: you tell it what to do using your query, not how to do it. Don't loop though all your rows to check which to delete: tell it what to delete and the database engine will find the best/fastest way to satisfy that goal.

Comment: `Error: unrecognized token: "1234A"`

Comment: I get an error when trying to connect the serialNum to connect with %s. 



`c.execute("delete from test where serial_num=%s;", serialNum)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\WinPython\WinPython-32bit-3.4.3.3\python-3.4.3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3035, in run_code
exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
File "<ipython-input-31-c75ef444a1b6>", line 1, in <module>\
c.execute("delete from test where serial_num=%s;", serialNum)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error`

Answer (score 0):

Hope I well interpreted your question

```
for row in c.execute('SELECT * FROM test WHERE serial_num = ?', serialNum'):
    # do whatever you want on row
    print row
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out a working solution:

`sql = "DELETE FROM test WHERE serial_num = ?"
c.execute(sql, (serialNum,))`

The comma after serialNum for some reason has to be there. Thank you @Michiel Arienfor the head start